# How can I prevent tons of apache processes spawning when I start apache and proceeding to kill my machine?

Tags: linux, apache, apache2, debian, apache-config

I have a highly trafficked application on one debian machine and apache has started acting strange.

Every time I start apache, tons of apache processes are spawned, the app doesn't load at all, and very quickly the whole machine freezes and must be powercycled to reboot.

Here is what I get for top immediately after starting apache:

```
top -   20:14:44    up         1:16,      2 users,    load average: 0.48, 0.10, 0.03
Tasks:  330 total,  5 running, 325 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 12.0%us,    21.4%sy,   0.0%ni,        65.7%id,   0.2%wa,  0.1%hi,  0.7%si,  0.0%st
Mem:    8179920k    total,     404984k used,  7774936k free,    60716k buffers
Swap:   2097136k    total,     0k used,       2097136k free,    43424k cached


10251 www-data  15   0  467m 8100 4016 S    6  0.1   0:00.04 apache2
10262 www-data  15   0  467m 8092 4012 S    6  0.1   0:00.05 apache2
10360 www-data  15   0  468m 8296 4016 S    6  0.1   0:00.05 apache2
10428 www-data  15   0  468m 8272 3992 S    6  0.1   0:00.05 apache2
10241 www-data  15   0  467m 8256 4012 S    4  0.1   0:00.03 apache2
10259 www-data  15   0  467m 8092 4012 S    4  0.1   0:00.04 apache2
10274 www-data  15   0  467m 8056 4012 S    4  0.1   0:00.03 apache2
10291 www-data  15   0  468m 8292 4012 S    4  0.1   0:00.03 apache2
10293 www-data  15   0  468m 8292 4012 S    4  0.1   0:00.03 apache2
10308 www-data  15   0  468m 8296 4016 S    4  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
10317 www-data  15   0  468m 8292 4012 S    4  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
10320 www-data  15   0  468m 8292 4012 S    4  0.1   0:00.04 apache2
10325 www-data  15   0  468m 8292 4012 S    4  0.1   0:00.04 apache2
```

And so forth.. with more apache2 processes.

Less than a minute later, you can see below that the load has gone from 0.48 to 2.17. If I do not stop apache at this point, the load continues to rise over a few minutes or less until the machine dies.

```
top -    20:15:34 up 1:17,       2 users,  load average: 2.17, 0.62, 0.21
Tasks:   1850 total,  5 running, 1845 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.3%us,      2.1%sy,    0.0%ni, 96.4%id,  0.0%wa,  0.1%hi,  1.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:     8179920k     total,     1938524k used,  6241396k free,    60860k buffers
Swap:    2097136k     total,     0k used,  2097136k free,    44196k cached
```

We have a firewall where we whitelist the addresses we know are allowed to hit our site.

Any ideas about what the problem might be are very welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Not programming related... Please fix formatting of the top output. Look at the Apache MPM worker if you need many concurrent connections; adjusting your keepalive settings might help too.

Comment: Thanks, we don't need all those concurrent connections. In fact things were working fine without so many connections before and have only started acting strange now although the traffic has declined.

Comment: Why are people voting this for closure? I run Apache on my machine when I do web development in PHP or Python, and this might be a problem that I face some day. I would say it's very much programming.

Comment: I think it would be a very good idea to post your Apache configuration, too. Are you using an embedded engine, e.g. PHP? Doesn't look so from the avg. size, but who knows. How much does the Apache process count rise?

Comment: I am facing similar issue, please add to the community and let us know the resolution you did.

Answer (score 42):

You have probably made the error of configuring Apache to use far more than all of your ram. This is an easy mistake to make.

I am assuming you are using a Prefork Apache, and an in-process application server (such as PHP or mod_perl). In this model, you will end up with a maximum of (MaxClients * max memory usage of your application per process) memory used. If you don't have nearly that much, it's time to decrease one, the other or both.

In the general case, this means decreasing MaxClients to the point where your server has enough ram to cope.

The default values typically used for MaxClients (150 is typical) are not suitable for running an in-process heavyweight application server on a modest machine if you are using the Prefork model (Most application servers either don't support, or discourage, the use of threaded models).

However, decreasing MaxClients will eventually cause the application to become unavailable, particularly if you have keepalives on and the keepalive timeout too long. Processes which are just keeping a connection alive (state K in server-status) still use a lot of RAM, and that may be a problem - try to minimise keepalive timeout, or turn it off altogether.

You need to keep an eye on server-status (as provided by mod_status).

Of course you should only make ANY of these changes if you understand the consequences. Think twice, change the config once. If you have ANY ability to test the changes with simulated load on a similar spec non-production machine, do so.

Comment: "Think twice, change the config once." +1

Answer (score 17):

use ps -aux | grep apache to find out the number of processes that apache is running on. Look out for the "RSS" column which gives an estimate of the memory used by each process. Alternatively you can use "top", where you shift + f and then select the %MEM column to sort the processes by memory usage.

The number of processes is determined by "MaxClients" directive in your apache.conf file. The way you come to this figure is as described by [this page](http://www.virtacoresupport.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=102);

1. SSH into your server as root.
2. Run top.
3. Press shift + m.
4. Note the highest RES memory used by httpd.
5. Hit Q to exit top.
6. Execute: service httpd stop (In debian, `sudo service apache2 stop`)
7. Once httpd is stopped, execute: free -m
8. Note the memory listed under "used".
9. Find the guaranteed memory for your VPS plan. Support can tell you how much you have guaranteed if you cannot find it.
10. Subtract the memory USED from the memory that your plan is GUARANTEED. This will give you your base FREE MEMORY POOL.
11. Multiply the value of your FREE MEMORY POOL by 0.8 to find your average AVAILABLE APACHE POOL (this will allow you a 20% memory reserve for burst periods).
12. Divide your AVAILABLE APACHE POOL by the highest RES memory used by httpd.  This will give you the MaxClients value that should be set for your system. (Round it to the nearest integer less than this value if it has a fraction component.)

The right value for "MaxClients" will ensure the right memory allocation for your apache server. That's how I solved it.

In Debian, apache conf file is at `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Answer (score 11):

Have you changed your configuration file recently? If yes, I trust you keep the old version for diffing?

If not, search for the "StartServers", "MaxSpareServers" and "MinSpareServers" directives. Generally you want to leave these at defaults, but it's possible that they were intentionally set high (bad idea) or accidentally set that way due to a bad config edit.

If this doesn't help, it's time to look outside Apache, for some process that's opening connections at a fast rate (could be that there's a testing process that's run amok).

First step is the access log. Second step is to run netstat, to see where the connections might be coming from. And if it's running on the same system, you can look in /proc/*/fd to find the two ends of the connection.

Comment: I can second that old version keeping very much. We even have /etc/ in our SCM.

Comment: I establish a git repository at the base of my /etc/apache2. Muhaha.

Answer (score 5):

This question is ancient, but I feel compelled to add an answer here because all of the existing answers are overlooking a key piece of information from the OP: After the load has begun to rise for a few minutes, `top` reports that there are still ample CPU & memory resources available. There is usually one culprit remaining, and that's I/O.

Check if there is a full partition with `df -h`. If not, see if your application is thrashing the disk using `vmstat 1 10` or `iostat 1 10` (these are provided by the 'sysstat' package on Debian/Ubuntu). If you still don't see an issue there, perhaps you have device level I/O errors or network trouble for network-mounted storage. Check the system and daemon log files.

Comment: Thanks for this! This gave me a deciding hint that hanging mountpoints were my problem ("/some/mount - device is busy" when attempting to `umount`). Apache kept ~slowly spawning processes, and my load was at ~180.

Answer (score 3):

As has been said (assuming Prefork Apache) - MaxClients = max processes at once.

If you find you are getting hammered with real traffic (and not a mis-configured StartServers/Min/MaxSpareServers), there are some other things you can do:

1. Set up a separate, lightweight
   apache process (or lighttpd) for
   your static content.  That way all
   the small, static stuff doesn't
   "pollute" your heavy-weight app
   process.  This can be on the same
   server, or a different one.  Doesn't
   matter.
2. Put a reverse proxy like Squid in
       front of your Apache process.  The
       reverse proxy will quickly suck down
       the content from Apache and store it
       in memory and then parcel it back
       out to the client.  This way AOL
       users on 14.4kb modems don't hog one
       of your valuable Apache slots.  As a
       bonus, such a setup can be
       configured to cache some of your
       content to reduce the load on your
       Apache processes.

Answer (score 2):

Your 'top' output shows that you have plenty of free memory, so I don't think that MaxClients is an issue (unless there is some problem with Apache allocating more than 2GB of memory?)  Your error log should show errors if it is having problems creating more children.

Most likely, your Apache processes really are using a lot of resources.  If you are running PHP apps, try installing eAccelerator which does a good job of optimizing and caching PHP code.   Other things might include heavy MySQL queries, a slow DNS resolver, etc.  Beyond that, it gets more into understanding what programs are being hit and what they are doing.