# how to solve PHP Fatal error: Out of memory, when I try this command "composer require laravel/ui" for auth file.?

Tags: laravel, cmd, composer-php

I try memory_limit=-1 or 526M or 1000M, but showing same error repeated.Please help me!!!!

D:\xampp\htdocs\elevenMedia>composer require laravel/ui
Using version ^2.0 for laravel/ui
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] Not enough storage is available to process t
his command.

VirtualFree() failed: [0x000001e7] Attempt to access invalid address.

VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] Not enough storage is available to process t
his command.

VirtualFree() failed: [0x000001e7] Attempt to access invalid address.

PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 908066816) (tried to allocate 4096 by
tes) in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Depen
dencyResolver/Solver.php on line 223

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 908066816) (tried to allocate 4096 bytes)
in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Dependency
Resolver/Solver.php on line 223

Comment: please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12178235/10573560

Comment: @OMR the given answer does not help after all, as Composer does not use `mod_php`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer Update failed -- out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299302/composer-update-failed-out-of-memory)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try installing this [package](https://github.com/hirak/prestissimo) that enables parallelization of the downloads.

```
composer global require hirak/prestissimo
```

Also when running your composer command use the -vvv flag if you are running into issues.

```
  composer require laravel/ui -vvv
```

Comment: Please add some further information to your answer. If dependency resolving does hot work, Prestissimo won't help after all

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I solved my problem by your answer.Your comment is very helpful for me.Thank you guy.

Comment: No problem! I find composer can be very finicky, and this helped solve my issue when I ran into it. Glad it helped!

Comment: @NicoHaase I am no expert here, but I think the parallelization somehow reduces the burden on memory usage. I know I was getting memory exhausted errors even with limit set to -1. Eventually I tried this, and it worked.

Comment: No. Prestissimo runs the downloads in parallel **after** dependencies have been resolved. If the resolving process fails (as shown in the error message: the solver runs out of memory), there is nothing to be downloaded in parallel

Answer (score 0):

You can try to increase de Memory Limit to 2 Gigabytes, as Laravel suggest, in your php.ini. On XAMPP it is located at C:\xampp\php\php.ini

```
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 2G
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a problem with missing swap partition. More info: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7348#issuecomment-414178276